# jQuery Autocomplete a input field for a filter table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my program, I have a table which I filter with an input field. You type something in the search/input field and the table gets filtered immediately without pressing enter.

Now I wanted to add autocomplete to this input field and it works but there is one problem. When I start typing something into the input field, I get suggestions. Now I can click on a suggestion and it gets written in the input field. That works just fine. But my table doesn't get filtered until I press enter and that's my problem. How do I make it that it automatically submits it/filters the table without pressing enter after selecting a suggestion?

Here are my two functions for the filtering and the autocomplete.

```
$("#searchInput").autocomplete({
    source: availableTags, //array with all possible search results of the table
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#searchInput").on("keyup", function () {
        var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        $("#contractTable tr").filter(function(){
             $(this).toggle($(this).find(".target").text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1) // I only want to search for two specific  cells of every row thats why I use find(".target")
        });
    });
});
```

I hope you get what I'm trying to achieve and on a side note I'm pretty new to JavaScript and jQuery so please have mercy with me :)

Comment: Could you provide a working example of the current state ?
This will help us alot to help you out instead of just providing the part that isn't working

Comment: There you go:
https://jsfiddle.net/24pchvgw/
So what I want it to do is that when you just type one letter and then select a suggestion it filters the table instantly. In this example you have to hit enter after selecting one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I fixed that for you:
https://jsfiddle.net/eakumopw/1/

Your Problem is you only hooked the filtering event to `"keyup"`. But selecting a autocomplete suggestions is no key-up event. Adding another event won't solve the problem either because the suggestions-box is a different element.

I check which events jquery-autocomplete supports (http://tutorialspark.com/jqueryUI/jQuery_UI_AutoComplete_Events.php) and found the `close()` event to be the solution for me.

I outsourced the filtering process into a new function `doFilter( value )` and made a call to that function on the `close` event of jquery-autcomplete.

```
$("#myInput").autocomplete({
  source: availableTags,
  close: function(event, ui) {
    console.log("close");
    doFilter($("#myInput").val().toLowerCase());
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Really appreciate it.